# No overload for method 'Select' takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, .net, overloading

I'm very new to C# and I'm trying to compile an application and I'm being presented with the following error message:

> No overload for method 'Select' takes 1 argument.

Here is the piece of code where I'm facing it:

```
    #region Tree events
    private void treeDims_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((System.Windows.Forms.Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
        {// handle CTRL + A
            if (e.KeyValue == (int)System.Windows.Forms.Keys.A)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                foreach (CDNM.Controls.Node n in this.treeDims.Nodes)
                {
                    n.Select(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void treeCubes_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((System.Windows.Forms.Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
        {// handle CTRL + A
            if (e.KeyValue == (int)System.Windows.Forms.Keys.A)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                foreach (CDNM.Controls.Node n in this.treeCubes.Nodes)
                {
                    n.Select(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

VS2010 highlights the error at `n.Select(false)`.

I know this should be basic but as I'm new, I have no idea on how to fix it.

Comment: It's hard to tell you how to fix it when we don't know what you're trying to do. What's your intention?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for `Select` to see what the arguments are supposed to be?

Comment: Who is `CDNM.Controls.Node`?

Comment: CDNM.Controls.Node belongs to DotNetMagic

Comment: the intention of the program is an Excel addin to connect to an OLAP database and retrieve and send information back

Comment: Is there an "Unselect()" or "Deselect()" method available? Speculating: It might be that always one Node has to be selected. So, you'd have to select another Node to deselect a given node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the select method on the control you are using does not accept a boolean parameter, but is instead an imperative method which simply causes the node in question to be selected. What you are trying to do is change the state from Selected" to "Not Selected."

I have not used the control library you are using, but I am willing to bet there is a boolean property setting similar to the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Treenode` control, which has a `TreeNode.Select()` method with no parameters, and a boolean property getter/setter `TreeNode.Select`.

Try this:

```
foreach (CDNM.Controls.Node n in this.treeDims.Nodes)
{
    n.Selected = false;
}
```

Of course, I could be wrong . . .

Answer (score 0):

I do not recognize the controls that you are using, but there are three basic approaches to resolving this type of issue:

1. Double-click on Select in the code and hit F1. If the control vendor has done their job properly, you will be taken to the help information for that method.
2. Right-click on Select and choose Go To Definition from the popup menu. This should take you to the list of available overloads. If it does not, then right-click on Node and do the same. This will show the list of properties and methods available for Node.
3. Browse the vendor's documentation. If this control was made inhouse, and there is no help documentation, consult the team responsible for the control.

Comment: this is what I found when going to definition:

public void Select();

Answer (score 0):

It means you have a method call or constructor somewhere in your code that either has a parameter where it shouldn't, or is missing a parameter that it needs.

Note: That code block seems a bit complex for someone "very new to C#. "

Comment: I think that's pretty obvious, don't you?

Comment: Its is complex, this is an Excel addin that connects to an OLAP Database